# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, naudio

The code that I got was from  [naudio record sound from microphone then save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982468/naudio-record-sound-from-microphone-then-save) and many thanks to Corey

This is the error message that I get when I run the code for the second or subsequent times. 
The first time it runs, it runs with no issues what so ever.

If I change the file name it works perfectly.

Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Basque.exe" to "bin\Debug\Basque.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Basque.exe' because it is being used by another process.    Basque

Could someone gave me some guidance to where I'm making my error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;

    namespace Basque
    {
        public partial class FlashCard : Form
        {
        public WaveIn waveSource = null;
        public WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;

        public FlashCard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StopBtn.Enabled = false;
            StartBtn.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartBtn.Enabled = false;
            StopBtn.Enabled = true;

            waveSource = new WaveIn();
            waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

            waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
            waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

            waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\Temp\bas0001.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);

            waveSource.StartRecording();
        }

        private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopBtn.Enabled = false;

            waveSource.StopRecording();
        }

        void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                waveFile.Flush();
            }
        }

        void waveSource_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveSource != null)
            {
                waveSource.Dispose();
                waveSource = null;
            }

            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Dispose();
                waveFile = null;
            }

            StartBtn.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void PlayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to put a Formclosing method with Application.Exit(); in it.  If it only works on the first try, it might be because the application isn't fully closing.

You can check if this will fix it when you check task manager.  Just make sure that your application isn't still there.  Even if it isn't still there, the Application.Exit(); might help.