# how to Naudio loopbackcapture Exclusive mode with PCM 8kHZ and 16bits per sample

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wasapi

how to capture audio from naudio in Exclusive mode with PCM 8kHZ and 16bits per sample?
what yuo have

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: How about googling it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982468/naudio-record-sound-from-microphone-then-save/17983876

Answer (score 0):

WASAPI won't let you open the soundcard in exclusive mode (or even shared mode) at arbritrary sample rates and bit depths. You have to pick from a fairly limited set of supported configurations. If you want exclusive mode, you'll still need to capture audio at 44.1kHz or 48kHz IEEE float, and then down-sample and convert to 16 bit yourself.

Or you can use WaveInEvent which will do the conversion for you, but you won't have exclusive access to the soundcard.